# STM32F4 get timer to work >2MHz

Tags: stm32, timer, hal-library

I have nucleo-401RE (STM32F401) board. I am trying to setup a timer (TIM4) to work above 2MHz (on bare-metal code).

Per the timer settings below I am supposed to get 10.5MHz. On scope, I am getting only 2MHz.

Am I making the correct configuration? Is there away to make it faster (I got same Hz when setting timer perload register to 3)

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "dbg_pin.h"

#define DBG_PIN_HIGH(p,x)   (p->BSRR = (uint16_t)x)
#define DBG_PIN_LOW(p,x)    (p->BSRR = (uint32_t) x << 16)
#define DBG_PIN_TOGL(p,x)   ((p->ODR & x)? DBG_PIN_LOW(p,x) : DBG_PIN_HIGH(p,x))
        
TIM_HandleTypeDef   hTimSlice;

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE2);

    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_OFF;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        return ;
    }

    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK) {
        return ;
    }
}

uint8_t timer_init()
{
    __HAL_RCC_TIM4_CLK_ENABLE();

    hTimSlice.Instance              = TIM4;
    hTimSlice.Init.Prescaler        = 0;
    hTimSlice.Init.Period           = 7;
    hTimSlice.Init.ClockDivision    = 0;
    hTimSlice.Init.CounterMode      = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    hTimSlice.Init.AutoReloadPreload= TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;

    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&hTimSlice) != HAL_OK){
        return 1;
    }
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM4_IRQn, 3, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM4_IRQn);
    return 0;
}

void TIM4_IRQHandler()
{
    if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&hTimSlice, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE) != RESET) {
        if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(&hTimSlice, TIM_IT_UPDATE) !=RESET) {
            __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(&hTimSlice, TIM_IT_UPDATE);
        }
    }
    DBG_PIN_TOGL(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_8);
}

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();

    setupDbgPin();
    timer_init();
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&hTimSlice);

    for(;;);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is `bare-metal code`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant no RTOS and no other code. (there is HAL)

Comment: Do you set GPIOC, pin 8 to high speed in setupDbgPin function?

Comment: yes. I did setup GPIOC-8 to high speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISR assembly list (below). Counted instructions execution time based on [arm M4 instruction set](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Programmers-Model/Instruction-set-summary/Cortex-M4-instructions) and found about (37) cycles. Note that it is just toggling a pin.

With 84MHz, (37) instructions * 12ns = 444ns.

And it is true, you can not achieve >2MHz (or worse) timer rate. I think the idea of using timer with higher rate is to use it with other services such as DMA.

```
70          if(__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&hTimSlice, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE) != RESET) {
      TIM4_IRQHandler:
08000f80:   ldr     r3, [pc, #40]   ; (0x8000fac <TIM4_IRQHandler+44>)
08000f82:   ldr     r3, [r3, #0]
08000f84:   ldr     r2, [r3, #16]
08000f86:   lsls    r0, r2, #31
08000f88:   bpl.n   0x8000f96 <TIM4_IRQHandler+22>
71              if(__HAL_TIM_GET_IT_SOURCE(&hTimSlice, TIM_IT_UPDATE) !=RESET) {
08000f8a:   ldr     r2, [r3, #12]
08000f8c:   lsls    r1, r2, #31
72                  __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_IT(&hTimSlice, TIM_IT_UPDATE);
08000f8e:   itt     mi
08000f90:   mvnmi.w r2, #1
08000f94:   strmi   r2, [r3, #16]
75          DBG_TOGL(GPIO_PIN_8);
08000f96:   ldr     r3, [pc, #24]   ; (0x8000fb0 <TIM4_IRQHandler+48>)
08000f98:   ldr     r2, [r3, #20]
08000f9a:   lsls    r2, r2, #23
08000f9c:   ite     mi
08000f9e:   movmi.w r2, #16777216   ; 0x1000000
08000fa2:   movpl.w r2, #256        ; 0x100
08000fa6:   str     r2, [r3, #24]
76        }
08000fa8:   bx      lr
08000faa:   nop     
08000fac:   lsls    r4, r3, #17
08000fae:   movs    r0, #0
08000fb0:   lsrs    r0, r0, #32
08000fb2:   ands    r2, r0
```

Comment: Only because you do thing inefficiently.  If you really wanted a fast output, you'd drive it from the timer hardware not an ISR.  And there are more efficient ways to write the ISR to do the minimal things necessary.

Comment: yes, i agree. I am just giving an example of doing "something". Now, i learned i can not do many things in timer ISR >2MHz. AND it is not just a setting problem.